# How to optimize choosing a subset of members under aggregate constraints?

Tags: optimization, combinatorics

**I'm looking for any algorithms or frameworks concerned with optimal selection of a subset of members of a set, subject to aggregate constraints placed on the heterogeneous features of the subset.** I'm having difficulty even coming up with the proper terminology to form this question, as I don't possess formal training in mathematics, so I'll do my best to describe the problem.

Consider a data set of N observations with P features (an N by P matrix). I want to select a subset S of the N observations such that constraints on aggregations of the P features are met. For example, consider that the average of P1 is required to be less than some constraint C1, and simultaneously the average of P2 is required to be greater than some constraint C2.

A "good" procedure would select the largest possible S subset of N that meets all of the constraints C (or comes close to the largest, considering time/complexity).

The pseudo-algorithm I'm imagining is extremely greedy, and goes like this:

- Drop a random observation from the current superset, resulting in the current subset
- Check the change in the aggregates of the features for the current subset relative to the current superset
- If the aggregates get closer to meeting the constraints, leave the dropped observation aside and start the algorithm over with the current subset as the superset of the next round (this would have to be some imperfect voting-type decision, as I wouldn't expect all changes to have the same direction)
- If the aggregates get further from meeting the constraints, replace the dropped observation and start the algorithm over with the same superset (this observation could be re-considered for removal in future steps once a new subset is established)
- Stop searching after all constrains are met

I realize there are several problems with this approach, not least of all the very large number of combinations possible while for the optimal set. **Is there any body of work that focuses on this type of optimal subsetting, and provides some tools to approach this problem?**

Comment: Are your constraints linear?

Comment: The constraints are given constants. The context is packaging together sets of loans that meet certain distributional requirements by the buyer.

Comment: Yes, but are they linear in the variables being constrained, as in, $aX_1 + bX_2 \leq 3$?  It makes a real difference whether they are or not.

Comment: I think so, but I'm thinking $aX_1 \leq 3$ and separately $bX_2 \leq 4$ (each variable has a separate constraint). However, I'm not sure what the coefficients in front of the variables are for (I think they are just 1?).

Comment: Well, as long as they aren't constraints like $X_1^{2.5}  \leq 5$ or $X_1*X_2 \geq 3$, or $\log x_1 + \log x_2 = 4$, for example, I'll assume they are linear, which makes the solution technique more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume the constraints are linear, i.e., sums and differences of the $X_{ij}$ for the "active" rows, we can solve this using off-the-shelf mixed integer programming solvers.  The R package lpsolve wraps around the freeware lpsolve solver and can solve problems like this, although there are plenty of others.

The problem can be formulated as a binary integer programming problem with linear constraints.  Define $y_i \in {0,1}$ where $y_i = 1$ if row $i$ is selected and 0 otherwise.  Since our objective is to choose the largest possible subset of the rows, the objective function is:

$$\max_y \sum_{i=1}^N y_i$$

I'll construct the constraints for the first two examples given above.  In the case of the first example, the average of $P_1$ is required to be less than $C_1$; I'll rewrite this as $\leq$, although in practice this might require a slight redefinition of $C_1$ itself, perhaps by subtracting a tiny number from it.  This would be formulated as:

$$\sum_{i=1}^Ny_iX_{i1} \leq NC_1$$

In the case of the second, the average of $P_2$ is required to be greater than $C_2$.  Substituting $\geq$ for $>$ leads to:

$$\sum_{i=1}^Ny_iX_{i2} \geq NC_2$$

The reason we can't, in general, use strict inequalities, is that if we have any continuous variables in our formulation, the problem will often reduce to something like "find the largest number $< 2$", for example, which doesn't have a solution.  "Find the largest number $\leq 1.99999$" does, however.

Now, if the constraint on, for concreteness, $P_1$ is that the average of $P_1$ *for the selected rows* $\leq C_1$, you'll need a different formulation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^Ny_i(X_{i1}-C_1) \leq 0$$

You can derive this by noting that the constraint as stated implies that the sum of $P_1$ for the selected rows $\leq$ the number of selected rows times $C_1$, and going from there.

If the constraints are nonlinear, however, you'll need more advanced solution techniques than many freeware solvers can provide.  The problem would still be formulated as a binary integer programming problem, but you'd need a solver that can handle nonlinear constraints.

Comment: Setting up the problem as a binary case of "include or don't include" each row really helps me, and thanks for the R package as well. I am still confused by the treatment of $N$ in the constraints: is $N$ a function of the number of selected rows? (If half of the rows are selected, does $N$ need to shrink by half in the formulation of the average of $P_1$?)

Comment: Yes, I had meant to ask you about that.  It really depends on what the criterion is, exactly.  I could see a criterion being "The average of $P_1$ over the selected rows $\leq C$" or being "The average of $P_1$ over all rows, with zeroes used for the non-selected rows, $\leq C$".  If it's the former, the constraints would have to be reformulated, but actually the latter seems more reasonable in a real-world application - what if one row out of 4,000 satisfied all the constraints for "average" value all by itself, so you just selected it?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an alternate version of the first constraint for the case where the average is taken over just the selected rows.

Comment: Thanks again for extending the answer. I see your point that a single row could satisfy the conditions, but would that happen if the objective was to maximize $y$ and other rows could be selected? My concern with the latter formulation (in your comment) is that zeroing-out rows would deflate the average of $P_1$, whereas the former is normalizing the average for the fewer rows. Is this a legitimate reason to choose the former criterion?

Comment: It really has to be a business (or customer) decision, I'm afraid, but I think that it *is* a legitimate reason to *prefer* the former criterion.  After all, businesses care about total revenue (for example), not just average revenue per unit sold (to continue the example.)  I can do quite well on the latter metric by selling one expensive thing once, but that's not how businesses are run.